# Using ASCII number to character in python

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to print a list of dicts to file that's encoded in latin-1. Each field is to be separated by an ASCII character 254 and the end of line should be ASCII character 20.

When I try to use a character that is greater than 128 I get "`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)`"

This is my current code. Could some one help me with how to encode a ASCII char 254 and how to add a end of line ASCII char 20 when using DictWriter.

Thanks 
my Code:

```
with codecs.open("test.dat", "w", "ISO-8859-1") as outputFile:

        delimiter = (chr(254))
        keys = file_dict[0].keys()
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(outputFile, keys, delimiter=delimiter)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        for value in file_dict:
            dict_writer.writerow(value)
```

Comment: Open the file with `file = codecs.open("test.txt", "w", "utf-8")`.

Comment: Use Python 3 if you can.

Comment: Can you confirm that you use a Python2.x? Python2 and 3 have different idioms here...

Comment: I am using python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

ASCII does only contain character codes 0-127.

Codes in the range 128-255 are not defined in ASCII but only in codecs that extend it, like ANSI, latin-1 or all Unicodes.

In your case it's probably somehow double-encoding the string, which fails.

It works if you use the standard built-in `open` function without specifying a codec:

```
with open("test.dat", "w") as outputFile:  # omit the codec stuff here
    delimiter = (chr(254))
    keys = file_dict[0].keys()
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(outputFile, keys, delimiter=delimiter)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    for value in file_dict:
        dict_writer.writerow(value)
```

Comment: You are almost right. As the codecs module expects unicode output, it first tries to convert the byte string containing chr(254) characters and fails with `UnicodeDecodeError` because the default conversion is ascii. So it is not a double encoding problem but the conversion to unicode required by codecs.

Comment: But I need the file in ISO-8859-1, if I remove the codecs, how else can I encode the file. Adding encode to writerow gives be Nonetype cannpt be encoded. Also, how can I add "END of LINE" ascii character?!